# Exclude Lambda function from deploy to a particular stage

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to exclude a Lambda function from being deployed via serverless to my `prod` stage within AWS.

A snippet from my serverless yaml looks something like -

```
functions:
  some-prod-function:
    handler: prodFunction.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /prod-function
          method: post
  some-dev-function:
    handler: devFunction.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /dev-function
          method: post
```

Is there a way to exclude `some-dev-function` from being deployed to prod?

Comment: I think that you should use different stages but not different api pathes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put those definitions on a different property and use variables in order to choose which definitions to use.

```
environment-functions:
  prod:
    some-prod-function:
      handler: prodFunction.handler
      events:
        - http:
            path: /prod-function
            method: post
  dev:
    some-dev-function:
      handler: devFunction.handler
      events:
        - http:
            path: /dev-function
            method: post


functions: ${self:environment-functions.${opt:stage}}
```

You may need to change this depending on how you specify your stage on deployment (`${opt:stage}` or `${env:stage}`).

Comment: This didn't work for me. However, if I put `environment-functions` under `custom`, I can make it work by referencing `${self:custom.environment-functions.${opt:stage}}`. I have no clue why this one works better, though.

Comment: @AndreasForslöw Maybe `serverless` has changed this since I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SLS 1.32.0

I wasn't able to get `functions: ${self:environment-functions.${opt:stage}}` to work. (Not sure why)

It returns the following:

```
A valid service attribute to satisfy the declaration 'self:environment-functions.dev' could not be found.
```

---

However, using the same logic in **dashmug's** answer, `file` worked for me:

*serverless.yml*:

```
functions: ${file(serverless-${opt:stage}.yml)}
```

*serverless-dev.yml*:

```
some-dev-function:
  handler: devFunction.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /dev-function
        method: post
```

*serverless-prod.yml*:

```
some-prod-function:
  handler: prodFunction.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /prod-function
        method: post
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Serverless framework you could use serverless plugin

> serverless-plugin-ifelse

Then

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-ifelse
```

If you want to exclude say func1

```
functions:
  func1:
    name: Function 1
    handler: lambda.func1
    events:
      - http:
          path: "path1"
          method: "post"
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:123456789012:userpool/us-east-1_0acCDefgh

  func2:
    name: Function 2
    handler: lambda.func2
    events:
      - http:
           path: "path2"
           method: "post"



func3:
    name: Function 3
    handler: lambda.func2
    events:
      - http:
           path: "path3"
           method: "post"
```

for us-east-1 . Then use below code snippet

```
- If: '"${self:provider.region}" == "us-east-1"'
        Exclude:
          - functions.func1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file for example

> env-functions.yml

and add content as below

```
prod:
    some-prod-function:
      handler: prodFunction.handler
      events:
        - http:
            path: /prod-function
            method: post
dev:
    some-dev-function:
      handler: devFunction.handler
      events:
        - http:
            path: /dev-function
            method: post
```

After this in serverless.yml set

```
functions: ${file(env-functions.yml):${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}
```